# Using Listbox as Table of Contents C# if Loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently trying to create a little app that has a table of contents in a listbox and when you click one of those items, a textbox is supposed to pop up and display a text. Well, somehow it is not working, if i click it once it does not work anymore after that.
Appreciate your help, thanks in advance

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;

        textBox1.Visible = false;

        textBox2.Visible = false;

        textBox3.Visible = false;

    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            loadTextBox1();
        }

        else if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            loadTextBox2();
        }
    }

    private void loadTextBox1()
    {
        textBox1.Visible = true;
    }

    private void loadTextBox2()
    {
        textBox2.Visible = true;
    }
```

Im really new to c# and programming at all, its probably gonna be an easy one lol

Comment: what is not working and what is happening currently?

Comment: are you making the visibility false ever??

Comment: okay, sorry for my bad explanation. the thing is that i want the program to show a text in a textbox  when i click an item in the listbox. Every item in the listbox has its own text. Right now it does that only for the first column what means the whole thing isnt working after that anymore

Comment: @JayNirgudkar, is that a bad thing?

Comment: @PhilipFrost.. let me understand... do you want the textBox to display the item you have selected in the ListBox?

Comment: @JayNirgudkar no, i mean when i click the item in the listbox, it is just supposed to show the textbox with a text i created. i guess i fixed it but thanks for your help too

Comment: @PhilipFrost please tell us your fix

Comment: @S.L. I did it just like you said, i changed them to this.invoke((methodinvoker)...) and it works perfectly fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
private void loadTextBox1()
{
    textBox1.Visible = true;
}
```

to

```
private void loadTextBox1()
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
      textBox1.Visible = true;
    });
}
```

and the same with loadTextBox2()

Additionally you should make **Visible=false** to the TextBox that is not getting visible.

This is because the call for the visible Change Comes from another thread than the UI thread and has to be invoked.

Further Information you **should** read when developing with WinForms can be found here

[How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When are you making it false?? I think you the problem is that you are not making the 2nd textbox false when you select the 1st one and vice-versa... try this.

```
private void loadTextBox1()
{
    textBox1.Visible = true;
    textBox2.Visible = false;
}

private void loadTextBox2()
{
    textBox2.Visible = true;
    textBox1.Visible = false;
}
```

you can do this when you have to show corresponding textblock having different text for each of the selected item.